# (Challenging) From the given figure, find the value of $x$ and $y$.

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

From the given figure, find the value of $x$ and $y$.

[image]

My Attempt,

$$\angle QPB=\angle QAB=50$$
$$2\angle x=\angle y$$

Now,  how to calculate further..?

Comment: May be $PB||AQ$?

Comment: @ Roman83, why? Any reason!?

Comment: $x$ can be anything between $0$ and $90$ degree.

Comment: @ Seyed, $x=55^\circ $!!

Comment: As I said it can be anything between $0$ and $90$

Comment: @Ramanujan You should listen to the smarter people who already told you and showed you (below, by giving you counterexamples!) that your problem does not have a unique solution. You are missing a piece of information that makes the problem uniquely solvable. You copied the problem wrong from the textbook or the chalkboard...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Look at your figure and note that $\angle PBA=\angle PQA = x$.

So, for fixed  $\angle QPB=50°$, changing the position of $P$ the value of $x$ is such that:

If $P\to B$ then $x \to 90°$,

if $P\to A$ then $x \to 0°$

---

In the figures you can see two situations.

[image][image]

Comment: @ Emilio Novati,  I couldn't understand. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you see that $\angle PBA= \angle PQA =x$ ? So if $P$ is near $B$ the angle become near $90°$, and if $P$ is near $A$ the angle become near $0°$.(For $P=B$  the line $PB$ become the tangent to the circle in $B$).

Comment: Yeah.  Then after??

Comment: @ Emilio Novati,  but the answer in my book is $x=55^\circ $ and $y=110^\circ $?

Comment: Maybe that there is another condition that fix the unique solution?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: @ Emilio Novati,  but why aren't we getting the answer I have stated??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54133/discussion-between-emilio-novati-and-ramanujan).